# What is the rule and guidance on naming a child "Ramadan"

Tags: halal-haram, authenticity, ramadan, children, naming

It has started becoming a normal thing in my area here, where people name their children either male or female some special name such as "Ramadan"

I found it difficult to find any authentic history behind naming children such name without any other name

Please can anyone help me with any guidance on giving such name to a child